# Do some colors trigger more neural activity in human brain?

Tags: evolution, neuroscience, brain, vision

On this [webpage](https://designshack.net/articles/graphics/the-science-behind-color-and-emotion/) I found this:

> The study found that “globs” in the brains of monkeys reacted differently to colored
>   stimuli, and reacted based on color. The brain was most triggered by specific colors
>   (red, then green, then blue) and colors with the most saturation. What this tells us is
>   that these colors immediately impact a user and draw attention.

*Question:* Do humans show similar increased neural activity to some colors?

Then I found a perception curve in this [webpage](http://www.dsource.in/course/visual-design-colour-theory/colour-perception-and-human-responses)
[image: A perception curve]

While this curve tells that yellow and green are seen before other hues while red and violet are difficult to perceive; I am not sure if yellow and green elicit more neural activity in the brain.

Anything to say on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper from [Stoughton & Conways (2008)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982208007392), where the linked [Design Shack webpage](http://www.dsource.in/course/visual-design-colour-theory/colour-perception-and-human-responses) refers to, explains that in the visual nucleus in the brainstem (LGN) as well as in the primary visual cortex, most of the color-selective neurons are selectively responsive to colors in the red-cyan axis (Fig. 1).

[image: colors]
<sup>Fig. 1. RGB color space. source: [Commodore 128 forum](http://c-128.freeforums.net/thread/86/colors)</sup>

This indeed means that **these colors evoke more brain activity** in these regions of the brain.

Note that a *[perception curve](http://www.dsource.in/course/visual-design-colour-theory/colour-perception-and-human-responses)* mentioned on the linked [D'Source](http://www.dsource.in/course/visual-design-colour-theory/colour-perception-and-human-responses) webpage is nonsense terminology

Comment: Why do you think it's nonsense?

Comment: D Would you elaborate on why do you think its nonsense?